# How to programmatically get the type of a specific declaration?

Tags: typescript

I want to programmatically analyze a certain number of files and generate an interface. Example:

```
const myFunc = (n: number) => n*2
makeGlobal('myKey', myFunc)
```

Should be converted to:

```
interface Window {
  myKey: (n: number) => number
}
```

What I really can't figure out is: **How do I force a TS to calculate a type for a second paramenter?** Same as how it work when you hover function in your IDE, but programmatically.

Comment: What exactly do you want to convert? Do you want to use ts-compiler API ? please share `makeGlobal` function

Comment: @captain-yossarian, 
- In real world `makeGlobal` is [contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge) from Electron. It get key and some Data and then expose it to another context as global variable. I want to find such calls and automatically generate a d.ts file that will be used in another context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find a way to do this easily with vanilla TS, but I succeeded with [ts-morph](https://ts-morph.com). Approximately as follows:

```
const myFunc = (n: number) => n*2
makeGlobal('myKey', myFunc)
```

```js
makeGlobalCallExpression
  .getArguments()
  .map(arg => arg.getType().getText())
```

```json
[
  "myKey",
  "(n: number) => number"
]
```

Comment: Also i publish tiny util to make TS interfaces from `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld` calls:
[dts-for-context-bridge](https://github.com/cawa-93/dts-for-context-bridge)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't create an interface, but you can use the `typeof` operator to infer the type of an object literal.

For example, since you mentioned this was for Electron, this is how I use it in my Electron projects to propagate the types of functions I pass to `exposeInMainWorld`:

In preload.ts, I define the API I pass to `exposeInMainWorld` in a separate variable and use `typeof` to extract the type. I then export the extracted type:

```
const bridge = {
  myFunc: (n: number) => n*2
};

export type ContextBridge = typeof bridge;

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", bridge);
```

Then, in a global declaration file in the renderer process, I import the type and add it to `Window`:

```
import type { ContextBridge } from '../main/preload';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    api: ContextBridge
  }
}
```

If I need to use `myFunc`, I import that declaration file, and `window.api.myFunc` is now visible to Typescript (and my IDE) with the correct signature.

Comment: Not a good practice. Import type from `preload` will also include all types from 'electron'. Types from node will pollute renderer side code. For example. if you add `settimeout` in your renderer source code, you will find this `settimeout` come from node instead of browser.